# Bluetooth module discovered by computer and not smartphones

Tags: bluetooth

I've been playing with [Groove Bluetooth Module](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/index.php?title=Grove_BLE_v1&uselang=en) (HM-11) and for some reason my computer can see it, but none of my cell phones can.

I've tried two Huawei P7 (BL 4.0 + BLE) as well as some Samsung Galaxy & some older sony with Bluetooth 2.0. None of the cell phones can see the device. Any ideas?

Comment: If I'm not wrong cellphones need an app to search for BLE devices instead of the regular bluetooth manager of your phone

Comment: Are you configuring the module as a slave? A phone will typically act as a master, so it will only see slave devices.

Comment: I did configure it as master. I'll try with slave.

Comment: Handoko you are right - in order to discover BLE device you need an application. Usual android search is different from BLE search.

Comment: One other thing to note, some phones, the iPhone at least, will not show Bluetooth devices that do not advertise profiles supported by the phone. For instance, the HC-05 only provides the SPP profile which the iPhone does not support, so an HC-05 will not show up when scanning for BT devices.